# wcf async with task and messageContract, why the parameters are not correct?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

In my service, I have all the methods async, and how I am using C# 4.0, O can't use the new CTP, so I have had implemented all the Begin/end methods.

When I need to call a method from the client, I use the following way:

```
Task<bool> myTask = Task<bool>.Factory.FromAsync(myProxy.BeginMethod1, miServicio.EndMethod1, CustomClass Parameters, null);
    result = await myTask;
```

This works, at least, when the CustomClass is a DataContract.

Now, I need to use a MessageDataContract, and when I use the same way, I get an error that say that the number of parameters is incorrect or the type. In this case i have the same, the Begin/end methods, the messageContract as parameters and a null as state.

I have checked the contract of the srevice, and the implementation, and I don't see any wrong, and the service compile correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: You say you're using C# 4.0 and can't use the new CTP, yet you're using `await`. How is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use the `TaskWsdlImportExtension` to create `Task`-based asynchronous WCF proxies on the client side. VS2012 does this by default, but you [have to set it up yourself](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/async/thread/47994f10-da43-4c7b-9756-6432a6188d98#4710c459-43e1-4705-8692-f0b5d1106881) on VS2010+AsyncCTP.

Comment: is a good option for production applications? If now I use this way, and later I want to use VS2012, my application will be compatible? I mean that I know sometimes this dlls are a preview version and in the final version has some changes.  Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely good for production. I *believe* that this component is fully compatible with VS2012, but I haven't heard anything official from the WCF/Async teams. You can ask them if you want to be 100% sure.